# Determine if a vector is orthogonal to a set

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I want to determine if the vector $v=\begin{bmatrix}1/2 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\3/2\end{bmatrix}$ is orthogonal to the set
 $Z=\{x ∈ ℝ^{4} | x_{1}-2x_{2}+3x_{4}=5 \}$.

So I started like this:

$x_{1}=5+2x_{2}-3x_{4}$

$
\begin{bmatrix}5+2x_{2}-3x_{4} \\ x_{2} \\ 0 \\x_{4}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}5 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0\end{bmatrix}+L(\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix})$

$(v,\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix})=0$ and $(v,\begin{bmatrix}-3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix})=0$ so $v$ is orthogonal to those vectors and he is orthogonal to every vector in the span of those two vectors.

Does this mean that $v$ is orthogonal to set $Z$? Why or why not? Vector (5,0,0,0) is what confuses me because he is not orthogonal to $v$. I know span of (2,1,0,0) and (-3,0,0,1) forms a plane, and v is orthogonal to that plane. Does adding vector (5,0,0,0) change that?

Comment: $x_3$ can take on any value in elements of $Z$, so you’ve got one more free variable to account for.

Comment: I think variable $x_{3}$ won't influence this result since $v_{3}$=0, so for any $x_{3}$, $v_{3}x_{3}=0$

Comment: @Nebeski : Its not orthogonal. Why you insist so ?

Comment: I am not insisting? I am asking if it is?

Comment: @Nebeski : I think the confusion here is that vector $v$ actually orthogonal to the set of vector that lie inside the plane (as you said the vectors spaned by $(2,1,0,0)$ and $(-3,0,0,1)$) but not the vector position of points of the plane (which is involve $(5,0,0,0)$).

Answer (score 0):

You only need find something in $Z$ that has non-zero inner product with the vector $v$.  Notice $v$ has first and fourth coordinates positive.  Find something in $Z$ with first and fourth coordinates positive.

Comment: I took vector w=(1,4,0,4) and (w,v) is not 0 so v is not orthogonal to Z. But in the solution of this problem in the book it says it is, so there is an error in the book...

Comment: @Nebeski The vector is indeed *normal* to the plane $Z$, but it is not orthogonal to any element of it. Someone is being sloppy with terminology.

Comment: @amd I didn't write normal anywhere here, just orthogonal. v is orthogonal to Z if it is orthogonal to every one of it's elements, which is not true. Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to say?

Comment: @Nebeski Before you declare your book’s answer erroneous, be sure that you’re clear on what it means by “orthogonal” in this context. $Z$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$, but it is a hyperplane nonetheless. It’s quite common in this situation to use “orthogonal” instead of the arguably more proper “normal.” Judging from context, this could be a trick question designed to catch you out on this particular point of pedantry, or more likely the author simply intended for you to verify that $v$ is normal to $Z$ (which can be done by inspection, by the way.)

Comment: Okay, so if I needed to verify that $v$ is normal to $Z$, how would I do that?

Comment: @Nebeski Show that’s it’s orthogonal to every vector that’s parallel to the plane $Z$, i.e., to the set $Z'=\{x\mid x+x_0\in Z\}$ for some fixed $x_0\in Z$. This can be done by examining the defining equation for $Z$.